# How can I create an associative array of objects using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js, associative-array, knockout-3.0

I am new to knockoutJS, but I'm working on storing this Vessel object into an Observable array. At the same time, I need to be able to be able to search for a specific object in the array by its unique id (mmsi) or its name. I assume that in order to do this, the array must be associative so that you can search through all the keys until you find the value you've searched. However, I'm not confident of my implemetation of this and could use some guidance.

Here is what I have:

```js
function Vessel(data) {
  this.mmsi = ko.observable(data.mmsi);
  this.lat = ko.observable(data.latitude);
  this.long = ko.observable(data.longitude);
  this.trueheading = ko.observable(data.trueheading);
}

function VesselViewModel() {
  // Data
  var self = this;
  self.vessels = new ko.observableArray([]);
  self.assoc = {};

  // Operations

  self.addVessel = function(m, lt, lg, th) {
    self.vessels.push(new Vessel({
      mmsi: m,
      lat: lt,
      long: lg,
      trueheading: th
    }));
  };
  self.removeVessel = function(vessel) {
    self.vessels.remove(vessel)
  };

  self.UpdateVessel = function(key, item) {
    if (self.assoc[key]) {
      self.assoc[key].value(item)
    } else {
      self.vessels.push(VesselViewModel.assoc[key] = {
        key: key,
        value: ko.observable(value)
      });
    }
  }
}
```

My apologies if this is completely wrong, but any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/162730): *why* do you think you need `UpdateVessel` with that particular signature, i.e. why would you need `key` as an argument? And what is the `.value()` function? Also note that you call `VesselViewModel.assoc[key]` which is *not* the same as `self.assoc[key]`. Please update your question, include (a repro for) the actual scenario/task/todo, possibly with the view code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think you need to do an associative array. You can get direct access to a knockout object through various types of binding. Here's a simple solution took me like 10 minutes to knockout.

In order to edit, since everything is observable, just hide/show form fields in line makes it stupid simple. When you are done click done and everything has already been updated.

It will at least give you an example of what you can do.

```
var model;
var data = [{mmsi: '12', lat: '12', long: '12', trueheading: '12'},
  {mmsi: '13', lat: '13', long: '13', trueheading: '13'},
  {mmsi: '14', lat: '14', long: '14', trueheading: '14'},
  {mmsi: '15', lat: '15', long: '15', trueheading: '15'}];

var Vessel = function (datas) {
    var self = this;
  self.mmsi = ko.observable(datas.mmsi);
  self.lat = ko.observable(datas.lat);
  self.long = ko.observable(datas.long);
  self.trueheading = ko.observable(datas.trueheading);

  self.editing = ko.observable(datas.editing || false);

  self.editVessel = function() {
    self.editing(!self.editing());
  }
}

var viewModel = function (datas) {

  var self = this;

  self.vessels = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(datas, function(vesselItem){
    return new Vessel(vesselItem);
  }));


  self.addVessel = function () {
    var newVessel = {
        mmsi: '',
      lat: '',
      long: '',
      trueheading: '',
      editing: true
    };
    self.vessels.push(new Vessel(newVessel));
  }

  self.removeVessel = function (vessel) {
    self.vessels.remove(vessel);
  }


}

model = new viewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/64m35xca/28/

Comment: Thank you! Also is there a way to modify these values within the javascript? Let's say I would like to update the lat and long of mmsi = 12. and I have the data = {mmsi: '12', lat: '45', long: '56', trueheading: '12'}; Is this possible to with knockout?

Comment: I think your best bet would be just to load the data again and "replace" the entire current observable array. `var data` is static but I assume you are going to be using ajax or something?

Either way you don't really need to update just mmsi: '12' you can replace the entire array of vessels.